# TableView do not enter in willDisplayCell

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, tableview

My goal is define my own cell style, with background, font and size. I try this.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    ScreenListElements *currentScreenElement = [self.screenDefBuild.elementsToTableView objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:currentScreenElement.objectName];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:currentScreenElement.objectName];

    }

    cell.textLabel.text = currentScreenElement.objectName;

    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{  
cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
}
```

I would like to change cell backgrond, but my app doesn't enter to willDisplayCell method. I have declared my class as:

```
@interface MyTableView : UIViewController  <UITableViewDataSource,NSCopying> {
}
```

Should i have something else? Or maybe is a better way to declare own cell style.

Comment: don't forget `UITableViewDelegate`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
@interface MyTableView : UIViewController  <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate ,NSCopying> {
}
```

the method

```
tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath
```

is delegate method of `UITableView`

**EDITED** (to make it correct & accepted answer)

setting delegate

```
[myTableView setDelegate:self];
```

Comment: r u sure? coz i added that line in my sample prog & it shows background of the view get colored. Is ur cell not getting colored at all OR is it colored in weird way.?

Comment: @SimpleMan - be sure to set the delegate. myTableView.delegate = self

Comment: @sosborn i've put this in my initializer, and won't help. Should i put it somewhere else?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i saw, that you didn't implement the "UITableViewDelegate" protocol, only dataSource...
So it surely doesn't enter delegate methods.

Be sure it is like so:

```
@interface MyTableView : UIViewController  <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate ,NSCopying> {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check `UITableviewCell` Delegate Protocol :

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
        willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell 
        forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{  

    cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue where I set all the things correct but if you have your function written manually you might miss the syntax and this error occurs:

> `(Instance method 'tableView(tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:)` nearly
> matches optional requirement `tableView(_:willDisplay:forRowAt:)` of
> protocol `UITableViewDelegate`

This way the function is not going to be recognised, write the function correctly:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
```

If the delegate is assigned to `self` this will work, else it's gonna show the error as you write the code.